# Any other ways to match url pattern in Spring security?

Tags: java, regex, spring, spring-security

I have the following sample configuration for `<sec:http>`

```
    <sec:http
authentication-manager-ref="blMyUserAuthenticationManager"
disable-url-rewriting="true"
request-matcher="regex"
pattern="(/logout/myuser|/login/myuser|/login/myuser?error=true|/login/myUser_post.htm|/myuser/account"
auto-config="false">
```

When I thought of doing it like this..

```
    <sec:http
authentication-manager-ref="blMyUserAuthenticationManager"
disable-url-rewriting="true"
request-matcher="regex"
pattern="(/logout/myuser|/login/myuser**|/myuser/**)"
auto-config="false">
```

I am getting **PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' error**

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance. Hope you will reply as soon as possible.

Comment: `*` is a symbol used in regular expressions. You probably need to escape it like `\*`.

Comment: You need to escape the `*` in the regex, but in Java strings you need to escape `\ ` too. So put `\\ ` before the `*`.

Comment: But when the example is like this.. `<sec:http pattern="/login/myuser**"/>` I didn't get such error!

Comment: why `/login/myuser\*` isn't matching `/login/myuser?error=true`?

Comment: @Matt I tried something like this `<sec:http pattern="/login/myuser\\**">`, it is matching only `/login/myuser` but not `/login/myUser_post.htm`

Comment: Try `.*` instead of `\\** ` I think I was mistaken on what I thought you were trying to do

Comment: You should also probably check out the last few paragraphs of [this section of the manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#request-matching).